# vim search numbers containing specific number of digits

Tags: vim, regular-expression, search

I need to find specific length numbers in a big document. I tried to use regex for this. For example, If I need to search for numbers with exactly 2 digits, I use `\d\d` (i.e. /d twice followed by a space). This works well.

But for finding 10 digit numbers it's not really feasible to type in `\d` 10 times.

Tried `\d{2}`, says '*E486: Pattern not found: \d{2}*'

Is there any quicker/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are different regular expression dialects; some (e.g. Perl's) do not require backslashes in the *quantification modifier* (`\d{2}`), some (e.g. sed) require two (`\d\{2\}`), and in Vim, only the opening curly needs it (`\d\{2}`). That's the sad state of incompatible regular expression dialects.

Also note that for matching *exact* numbers, you have to anchor the match so that `\d\{2}` won't match to digits (`12`) in `123`. This can be done with *negative look-behind* and *look-ahead*:

```
\d\@<!\d\{2}\d\@!
```

Comment: Perfect. Can you please one liner info on the regex? Would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: For someone struggling with the basic regexp syntax, look-behind/ahead is pretty advanced. I probably cannot describe it better than the built-in `:help /\@<!` and `:help /\@!`. Don't worry if you don't immediately understand everything; as I said, this is pretty advanced.

Comment: You can also put `\v` at the beginning of the regex if you wish to avoid having to escape the `{`, see `:help magic` for more information (it makes vim regex behave a bit more like perl regex, though there are still differences).

Comment: Thank's a lot: `\d\{4}` in Vi it's a trivial one at all

Answer (score 13):

Try the following:

```
\d\{2}
```

and you should use `\` not `/`

You can find out more about the regular exression of vim on this [site](http://vimregex.com/) or in `vim` with `:help regular`.

Answer (score 3):

Escaping brackets works: `\d\{2\}`

Answer (score 1):

Not as pretty, but this worked for me for 5 digits in a log file.

```
/\<\%(\d\d\d\d\d\)\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Search numbers of fixed length say 5

```
/\d\{5\}
```

match 12345, 123456

As numbers more than 5 digits contain substring of 5 digits, they will be found too.

word boundary start

```
\<
```

word boundary end

```
\>
```

Then use below to search numbers of exact 5 digits

```
/\<\d\{5\}\>
```

match 12345 but not 123456

Use below to search numbers of 5 or more digits.

```
/\<\d\{5,\}\>
```

Use below to search numbers of 5 to 8 digits.

```
/\<\d\{5,8\}\>
```

Use below to search numbers of 8 or less digits.

```
/\<\d\{,8\}\>
```

Shortcut numbers of 1 or more digits

```
/\d\+
```

Answer (score -2):

For someone like myself reaching this page simply to look for a pattern matching ***any*** length of digits:

```
\d\+
```

(It took me some time to figure out the mandatory extra escaping \ before +)

Comment: `+` quantifier stands for 1 or more occurrence. This regular expression matches 1 or more occurrences of digits.