# Pattern repetition and regexp

Tags: regular-expression

Take the pattern

```
[UGLER]*
```

Can the string UUG match against it? I mean to say, is repetition allowed?

Answer (score 4):

In principle yes, but that *may* depend on the regex flavor you are using. At the very least, [BRE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_syntax.html), [ERE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html) and [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) will all match that string. The expression `[UGLER]*` means *match 0 or more consecutive characters from the set of U,G,L,E or R*.

You can test this for different regex types easily enough:

- BRE

  ```
  $ echo UUG | grep '[UGLER]*'
  UUG
  ```
- ERE

  ```
  $ echo UUG | grep -E '[UGLER]*'
  UUG
  ```
- PCRE

  ```
  $ echo UUG | grep -P '[UGLER]*'
  UUG
  ```

Of course, since you are looking for *zero* or more, it will also match things you might not be expecting:

```
$echo "foobar" | grep  '[UGLER]*'
foobar
```

If the regex flavor you are using supports it, use the `+` instead of `*`. For example, with PCRE:

```
 $echo -e "UUG\nfoobar" | grep -P '[UGLER]*'
 UUG
 foobar
 $echo -e "UUG\nfoobar" | grep -P '[UGLER]+'
 UUG
```

Comment: all regexp flavours support `+` - but some require you to write it as `\+`

Comment: @CraigSanders OK, thanks.  I didn't want to generalize because for all I know there is some kind of obscure regex engine from the 60s that only works in lisp machines and has its own weird syntax ;).

Comment: @CraigSanders, no, standard BRE don't support `\+`, that's a GNUism. See [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90884/22565) for more details.

Comment: Stephane is (of course) right. For portability, instead of `[UGLER]+`, use `[UGLER][UGLER]*` (ie, one occurence, followed by 0, 1 or many occurence)

Comment: @stephane - thanks. it's been so long since i used a non-GNU sed or grep that i'd completely forgotten that `+` was non-standard.  I usually install GNU tools under /usr/local/ within hours or minutes of using non-GNU systems like *bsd or solaris, just to keep myself sane.

Comment: @OlivierDulac, note that `grep -E '[UGLER]+'` and `grep '[UGLER]\{1,\}'` are standard, it's just `grep '[UGLER]\+'` that isn't.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks! I now wonder if I will not alias "grep" to "grep -E" ^^ I'll go read about the potential side effects... [iirc, changing interpretation of some things, but I need to know exactly which ones]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your pattern is a fileglob pattern and not a regexp, then yes it will match a filename called 'UUG'.  The pattern will match any file starting with U, G, L, E, or R.

you can test this yourself with:

```
touch UUG
ls -l [UGLER]*
```

If the pattern is a regexp, then it will match **ANY** string, because you are matching against zero-or-more instances of [UGLER].  If you want to match 1-or-more rather than zero-or-more, then use `+` instead of `*`