# Using a perl compatible regex with GNU grep -P

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm using this regex `(?<=\[')[^,]*` on a file containing the following line `disk = ['OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w']`

I want that to return `OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img`

How do I use `grep` to make it work?

I've tried `grep -P "(?<=\[')[^,]*"` but it returns the whole line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the `-o` switch so that `grep` only returns what matches the pattern you're grepping for:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=\[')[^,]*" data.txt 
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `sed` without the lookaround assertion for greater portability (`-o` may not be available for your `grep`):

```
sed "s!['\(\[^,\]*\),.*\$!\1!;t;d;p" data.txt
```

Note the "strange" use of backslash escapes here. It's due to the fact that `sed` uses BREs by default (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90653/why-do-i-need-to-escape-regex-characters-in-sed-to-be-interpreted-as-regex-chara)).

Speaking of portability, why not just use Perl?

```
perl -nle "print \$1 if /\['([^,]*)/" data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

@slm already gave you the canonical answer. Here are a few more options:

Use `awk` and `'` as field delimiter (assuming all lines have the same format):

```
$ awk -F "'" '($1~/ = /){print $2}'
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
```

Do the whole thing in perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /\[.(.*?).\]/' data.txt 
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
```

Use a simpler regex and parse the results:

```
$ grep "\[.*\]" data.txt | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
$ grep -o "\[.*\]" data.txt | perl -pe "s/[\[\]']//g"
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
$ grep "\[.*\]" data.txt | sed 's/.*\[.\(.*\).\]/\1/'
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
$ grep "\[.*\]" data.txt | perl -pne 's/.*\[.(.*?).\].*/$1/'
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
$ grep "\[.*\]" data.txt | perl -lne 'print $1 if /\[.(.*?).\]/'
OVS/sdasd/asdasd/asdasd/something.img, w
```