# Replace regex capture group content using sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to edit my nginx.conf file programmatically, which contains a line like this:

```
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

which I want to look like this:

```
        access_log /dev/stdout;
```

I believe the regex [`^\s*access_log([^;]*);`](http://rubular.com/r/hShEfoLX18) will capture the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` part in a capture group, but I'm not sure how to correctly replace the capture group with sed?

I've tried

```
echo "        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;" | sed 's/^\s*access_log([^;]*);/\1\\\/dev\\\/stdout/'
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

if I try `sed -r` then there is no error, but the output is not what I expect:

```
 /var/log/nginx/access.log\/dev\/stdout
```

I'm trying to be smart with the capture group and whatnot and not search directly for "access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;" in case the distribution changes the default log file location.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A couple of mistakes there.

First, since `sed` uses basic regular expressions, you need `\(` and `\)` to make a capture group. The `-r` switch enables extended regular expressions which is why you don't get the error. See [Why do I need to escape regex characters in sed to be interpreted as regex characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90653/why-do-i-need-to-escape-regex-characters-in-sed-to-be-interpreted-as-regex-chara).

Second, you are putting the capture group in the wrong place. If I understand you correctly, you can do this:

```
sed -e 's!^\(\s*access_log\)[^;]*;!\1 /dev/stdout;!' your_file
```

Note the use of `!` as regex delimiters to avoid having to escape the forward slashes in `/dev/stdout`.

Answer (score 7):

In your regexp you should know that `\No.` is the *back reference* to pattern within brackets `()`. So regexp should be `'s@^(\s*access_log ).*$@\1/dev/stdout/;@'`

I can offer

```
sed '/access_log/s|/[^;]\+|/dev/stdout|'
```

HINT: Whether you intend to use `/` inside the patern you are free to change `s///` for every symbol you'd like `s###` for example

Answer (score 6):

Rather than capture it, why not just find it and do a substitution? I.e.:

```
sed "/access_log/ s| /.*;| /dev/stdout;|"
```

It searches for lines that match "`access_log`" then on any lines that do it will replace " `/whatever/path/is/there;`" with " `/dev/stdout;`"

Comment: The `/access_log/` string in Jeremy's is known as an "address" for the `sed` command. Often, numbers (indicating line numbers) are used as addresses to sed but today I learned that regular expressions can be used as addresses too. Thanks Jeremy!

Comment: Thanks for the note dgtc - I learned something too! I knew that the line numbers were an "address", but it never occurred to me that a search string was also an "address" (it seems obvious now, I just hadn't made the connection...). :)