# Sed substitution middle of string

Tags: sed, terminal

Trying to write a one liner to change my wallpaper through a config file. Tried adapting from: [Replace regex capture group content using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165589/replace-regex-capture-group-content-using-sed) but I can't seem to get it right.

My config file contains the following string:

```
output * bg ~/pictures/wallpapers/old-wallpaper.jpg fill
```

I want to change the path in this string to something else.

This one makes most sense to me but doesn't capture correctly:

```bsh
sed "/output \* bg /s|.* fill|~/path/to/foobar.jpg fill|" sed_file

output * bg ~/pictures/wallpapers/old-wallpaper.jpg fill
```

This one looks completely wrong but seems to get the job done. Although I think it replaces anything that starts with `output`.

```
sed "/output \* bg/s| .* fill| \* bg ~\/path\/to/foobar.jpg fill|" sed_file

output * bg ~/path/to/foobar.jpg fill
```

Comment: I would take a look at: `awk '/^output/{ $4="foo" } { print }' file`

Comment: cool! that's a lot easier to do.. settled for `awk '/^output \* bg/{ $4="foo" } { print }'`

Comment: What's actually showing the image as wallpaper? It could probably be made to read a list of files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed. I assume your path contains no spaces or pipes. I switched from `s///` to `s|||`.

```
sed -E 's|^(output \* bg) [^ ]+ |\1 foo |' file
```

Output:

```
output * bg foo fill
```

> `-E`: use extended regular expressions