# How can I swap the order of each two character pair in a string?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to automate the swapping of characters 1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc, in a an arbitrary-length string of hex characters.

Example:

```
A627E39B
```

becomes:

```
6A723EB9
```

It seems like this should be possible using sed or one of the other *nix text utilities, but so far I have not been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 8):

You can use back-references:

```
echo A627E39B | sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g'
```

This finds all occurrences of two characters and swaps them.

As [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) pointed out, enabling extended regular expressions ([`-E` w/ GNU, BSD, or `toybox` `sed`s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90653)) avoids having to escape the parentheses:

```
echo A627E39B | sed -E 's/(.)(.)/\2\1/g'
```

Answer (score 4):

There’s a tool that specifically, natively supports that function:
`dd` with the `swab` (**swa**p **b**ytes) conversion:

```
% echo ABCD | dd conv=swab
BADC
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
5 bytes (5 B) copied, 0.000109277 s, 45.8 kB/s
```

You’ll want to add `2> /dev/null` to discard the log output:

```
% echo ABCD | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null
BADC
```

Warning: This will do pretty much what you want if you send it
an even number of (printable) characters.  But, if you give it
an odd number of printable characters — let’s say 2*n*+1 —
then `dd` will take the newline at the end
as the (2*n*+2)<sup>th</sup> character,
and swap it with the (2*n*+1)<sup>th</sup>.  So,

```
% echo ABCDE | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null
```

sends

<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>
<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>\n</kbd>

to `dd`, which gives you

<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>\n</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>

back; this will look like

```
BADC
E
```

You can work around this by specifying the `-n` option to `echo`
to suppress the newline at the end
(or just use `printf` without adding a newline). 
If you’re displaying the output to the screen, then, for completeness,
you should add a newline at the very end:

```
% echo -n ABCDE | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null; echo
BADCE

% printf "%s" ABCDE | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null; printf "\n"
BADCE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `perl`:

```
$ echo A627E39B | perl -CLS -nle 'print map {~~reverse} unpack "(a2)*"'
6A723EB9
```