# How to substitute text from latex file preambles with sed?

Tags: sed, latex

I wrote the following sed code that I haven't found the way to make it work...

```
sed -is 's/documentclass\{standalone\}/documentclass\[class\=memoir\]\{standalone\}/gp' *.tex
```

Am I using escape sequences the wrong way?  The following is the error returned:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 76: Invalid content of \{\}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BRE (basic regular expression) mode (i.e. without the `-E` or `-r` command line option) braces are not special, while escaped braces are used for quantifiers like `\{1,3\}`. The error message is because `standalone` can't be parsed as a numeric quantifier. So you want `{standalone}`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'documentclass{standalone}' | sed 's/documentclass{standalone}/documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}/gp'
documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}
documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}
```

Alternatively keep the escaped braces, but use ERE (extended regular expression) mode:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'documentclass{standalone}' | sed -r 's/documentclass\{standalone\}/documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}/gp'
documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}
documentclass[class=memoir]{standalone}
```

Note that in either case, nothing in your RHS needs escaping.

See also:

- [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)
- [Why do I need to escape regex characters in sed to be interpreted as regex characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90653/why-do-i-need-to-escape-regex-characters-in-sed-to-be-interpreted-as-regex-chara)

Note also that at least in GNU sed, `-is` will edit the file in-place, creating a backup file with suffix `s`. If you want to pass the `-i` and `-s` options you must do so separately or in the other order `-si`. However iirc `-i` implies `-s` so the latter is likely superfluous.